# Using Flexbox to Display Content Not Working HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with an image and text. Currently, I'm using margins and padding, but would it be better with justify content and align content?

Currently, what I'm doing isn't working correctly, I can't seem to get the images to line up with their text. Is there a way for me to put the text and image inline with each other.

[image]

Website:[image]

```css
/*flexbox*/
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    width: 80%;

    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    
    border: solid .125em #00aaff;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.9;
}

section > * {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    padding: 1em;
}

/*Images*/
figure img {
    width:50%;
    margin-left:5em;
}

/*Text*/
p{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left:-3em;
}
```

```html
<section id="display">   
        <figure id="image1">
            <img src="images/512x512.png" alt="Dynamo">
        </figure>
         
        <article>
                <p><span id="name">Houston Dynamo</span></p>
                <p>Sport Science/Sport Performance Intern</p>
                <p><time datetime="2018-01-01"></time>January 2019 - Present</p>
        </article>
        
        <figure>
            <img src="images/UW-Logo.png" alt="UIC">
        </figure>
        
         <article>
                <p><span id="name">University of Madison Wisconsin-Madison</span></p>
                <p>Strength and Conditioning Coach, Graduate Assistant</p>
                <p><time datetime="2011-08-01"></time>August 2018 - <time datetime="2014-12-31">December 2018</time></p>
        </article>
```

Comment: reset the default margin of `figure` (or only `margin-top`), see https://jsfiddle.net/c2amo01k/

Answer (score 0):

Really helps to avoid flex wrap for a layout like this. I have wrapped each "row" of you layout in a div with class `flex-wrapper-thingy` to which I have applied `display: flex` so the flexbox layout is happening in each row.

Now the flexbox config is just in relation to each pair of `figure` and `article` elements. `align-items: center` is the perfect way to get these items to line up nicely despite their different heights. Now check out how few rules are needed to adjust the spacing and relative sizing.

```css
/*flexbox*/
section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid .125em #00aaff;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-wrapper-thingy {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; // maybe you want to try "center" too
}

section > * {
  padding: 1em;
}

/*Images*/
figure {
  width: 50%;
}

/*Text*/
article {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="display">
  <div class="flex-wrapper-thingy">
    <figure id="image1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Dynamo">
    </figure>
    <article>
      <p><span id="name">Houston Dynamo</span></p>
      <p>Sport Science/Sport Performance Intern</p>
      <p><time datetime="2018-01-01"></time>January 2019 - Present</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-wrapper-thingy">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="UIC">
    </figure>
    <article>
      <p><span id="name">University of Madison Wisconsin-Madison</span></p>
      <p>Strength and Conditioning Coach, Graduate Assistant</p>
      <p><time datetime="2011-08-01"></time>August 2018 - <time datetime="2014-12-31">December 2018</time></p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This looks good in this screen size and solves the issue. I just now need to go and create media breaks and move each one every break

Answer (score 0):

Check this out too, I just removed `margins` that's causing the image / figure to go down that's why its not in same level as the `article`

```css
/*flexbox*/
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid .125em #00aaff;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.9;
}

section > * {
  margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    padding: 1em;
     border:2px solid black;
}
article{
  padding-left:20px;
}
figure,article{
  margin: 10px;
}
/*Images*/
figure img {
    width:100%;
}
/*Text*/
p{
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="display">   
        <figure id="image1">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Dynamo">
        </figure>
         
        <article>
                <p><span id="name">Houston Dynamo</span></p>
                <p>Sport Science/Sport Performance Intern</p>
                <p><time datetime="2018-01-01"></time>January 2019 - Present</p>
        </article>
        
        <figure>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="UIC">
        </figure>
        
         <article>
                <p><span id="name">University of Madison Wisconsin-Madison</span></p>
                <p>Strength and Conditioning Coach, Graduate Assistant</p>
                <p><time datetime="2011-08-01"></time>August 2018 - <time datetime="2014-12-31">December 2018</time></p>
        </article>
        </section>
```

You may want to see this in full view. just hoping this help.